# Use localStorage to start or stop a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to use localStorage to control a script, but don't know how to hook into it.

I have this script (a website tour plugin):

```
 $('#starttour').powerTour({'options'});
```

That I am trying to start and stop (and keep stopped on return visits) with buttons.

```
    $('#openTour').click(function(){
        localStorage.removeItem('pt-run');
        location.reload();          
    });     

    $('#stopTour').click(function(){
        $('#starttour').powerTour('destroy');       
        $('#powertour-overlay').css('display', 'none');     
        localStorage.setItem("pt-run", "no")
    });
```

My question is - How do I get localStorage to hook into this?

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Are you looking for debugging advice or just general how to info?

Comment: I find it kind of bold to ask for public help with a license like this: "Licence: NOT free".

Comment: I just didn't know how to accomplish what I needed, but I solved it. - Thank You

Comment: @nietonfir good point - I have removed the fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
    if(localStorage.getItem("pt-run") == null){
        $('#starttour').powerTour({ });
     }
```